# Importing data from JSON file to MySQL database using java

Tags: java, mysql, json, parsing, jdbc

I currently ran into a requirement of having the data dynamically imported into `MySQL` database (But by using `java`).

I am not sure what is the best practice for this but let me put forward my scenario.

The json can be dynamic and its uncertain of what will be in the json each time I read from an API endpoint
for example:

```
"table1" : {
    "field1" : "value1",
    "field2" : "value2",
    "field3" : "value3"
}
```

One time the json will be like this

the other time it might be like

```
"table2" : {
    "field1" : "value1",
    "field2" : "value2",
    "field3" : "value3",
    "field4" : "value4"
}
```

so my question is should I parse the json and compare it with the fields in table which matches the json name?

or is there any library available in java which will enable me to easily and efficiently handle this.

**NOTE:** I have to prepare this as a service which will continously scan a given API after certain interval and the respective JSON needs to get imported into the table it belongs, and if the table doesn't exist then it must get automatically created.

Thanks all for your patient reading and support, this is a new kind of requirement which I have never handled.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Doesn't appear as a good practice IMO. Ensure that the json delivers the right table name. Then gather the table metadata to get the keys and generate a list of inserts based on the available values (it's also easier to pick the right validator if each table has their own validator.). If it's not valid, then too bad. Report it accordingly.

Comment: Yes @KarelG this is not a good scenario to handle, but the data comes from a legacy application and I dont have permission to alter the json API's. Validator seems to be a good solution but the table names and schema is uncertain, meaning there can be new tables coming in the json file and we have to generate the table if it doesn't exist, is there any alternate best practice for this? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [google-gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or jackson api to make your code more efficient

Comment: Yes naib, I am using jackson, thanks, but I am in search of a library which will save time rather than coding by myself, if any please inform me, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my project i used google-gson API. It worked very well and it was painless. 
You can find the project with it's description [here](https://github.com/google/gson).

Below is a simple example from API [docs](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) wich supports multi-dimensional arrays, with arbitrarily complex element types: 
Collections Examples

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Collection<Integer> ints = Lists.immutableList(1,2,3,4,5);

// Serialization
String json = gson.toJson(ints);  // ==> json is [1,2,3,4,5]

// Deserialization
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Integer> ints2 = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
// ==> ints2 is same as ints
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! but this is not the requirement, I need to import the data in the json into mysql by using java