# Import json file to mysql database using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, json

How to import JSON file to MySQL database. It would be good if I can get a stored procedure, or a java program that will automatically push the required file to MySQL DB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing data from JSON file to MySQL database using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838994/importing-data-from-json-file-to-mysql-database-using-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your JSON looks like this :

```
    {
           "employee": 
           {
              "id": "100",

              "name": "ABC",

              "address": "New York"
           }
    }
```

We can parse the JSON using JSON parser. Have a look in my code :

```
public int insertJSONtoDB() throws Exception {
    int status = 0;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase", "root", "root");
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("insert into  employee values ( ?, ?, ? )");
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c.\\employee.json")); 
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        String id = (String) jsonObject.get("id"); // from JSON tag
        preparedStatement.setString(1, id); // to the Database table

        String name = (String) itemize.get("name");
        preparedStatement.setString(2, name);

        String address = (String) itemize.get("address");
        preparedStatement.setString(3, address);

        status = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```